# Image Size on Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Im creating a very simple aplication for pratice, and I´m having some trouble with Kivy GUI.
I would like to get all the images on the same size,and if it´s possible creat aline that separetes  all the vertical box layouts.

:
    name:'Prices'

```
BoxLayout:

    orientation:'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            source:'back_azul.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        height:'30dp'
        size_hint_y:None

        Button:

            size_hint_x:0.25
            text:"Back to Menu"

            opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else .5
            background_color:0,0,0,0
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
            font_size:20





    BoxLayout:
        background_color:0,10,10,1
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"camisa.jpg"

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa social"
            bold:True
            font_size:11
        Label:
            text:"R$: 8,00"
            font_size:15

    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"peca.jpg"

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa Polo"
            font_size:11
            bold:True

        Label:
            text:"R$:6,00"
            font_size:10
    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"terno.jpg"

        Label:
            text:"01 Terno c/Calca"
            font_size:11
            bold:True
        Label:
            text:"R$: 28,00"
            font_size:10
    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"vestido.jpg"
        Label:
            text:"01 Vestido"
            font_size:11
            bold:True
        Label:
            text:"R$: 70,00"
            font_size:10
```

[image]

Comment: your images seem to have different ratios. Would you like to match the width or the height of all images or would you like to "stretch" some so that width and size are identical?

Comment: : name:'Prices' that is the fourth line of your post. Is it code? Why is it there?

Comment: name:'Prices', define the name of the screen I´m using

Comment: I would like the images to match the same width.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Same width of the images:

**Option 1**: you can set the width, but must set the corresponding size hint to None.

```
Image:
    size_hint_y: None
    source:"Astronaut3.jpg"
    width: 100
    allow_stretch: True
```

**Option2:** use the size_hint

```
Image:
    source:"Astronaut2.jpg"
    size_hint_x: 0.4
    allow_stretch: True
```

### Creating a line

Again there are different options. You could use the Line from kivy Graphics. An easy and straightforward solution is to use a Label and make it your color of choice and then make it really small.

```
Label:
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 1
```

---

### Sample App

Here are all the things mentioned in one sample App. It is not good practice to repeat yourself when coding, but I am doing it here to mirror your question as close as possible.

[image]

**sample app example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation:'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"Astronaut2.jpg"
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            allow_stretch: True

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa Polo"
            font_size:11
            bold:True

        Label:
            text:"R$:6,00"
            font_size:10
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: (1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 1

    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            source:"Astronaut3.jpg"
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            allow_stretch: True

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa Polo"
            font_size:11
            bold:True

        Label:
            text:"R$:6,00"
            font_size:10

    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: (1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 1

    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            size_hint_y: None
            source:"Astronaut2.jpg"
            width: 100
            allow_stretch: True

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa Polo"
            font_size:11
            bold:True

        Label:
            text:"R$:6,00"
            font_size:10
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: (1,1,1,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 1

    BoxLayout:
        padding:5
        Image:
            size_hint_y: None
            source:"Astronaut3.jpg"
            width: 100
            allow_stretch: True

        Label:
            text:"01 Camisa Polo"
            font_size:11
            bold:True

        Label:
            text:"R$:6,00"
            font_size:10


""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much